# Create tables in SQL Server using SQL code from RStudio

Tags: sql-server, rstudio

I have SQL code like below, but with more columns and I also create a nonclustered index on this table within the sql script.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = ModelOutput)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE ModelOutput
    (
        [OutputID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Prediction] [int] NOT NULL,
        [CreateDate] [datetime] DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), getdate()),
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
END;
```

This code is saved in a file called `CreateTable.sql` which I want to run using RStudio.

Currently, my R code looks like:

```
#Read SQL file
sqlcode = read_file(file = "CreateTable.sql")

#Run SQL code
DBI::dbSendQuery(conn = con, statement = sqlcode)
```

However, when I tried to figure out why it didn't seem to be running, I found that `dbSendQuery()` only works with select statements (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/DBI-advanced.html). So then I found `dbCreateTable()` but that only works if I have created the table using R. I don't want to do that since I can't set the same column defaults or create an index--as far as I know.

I have looked around and cannot find any way to run a create table SQL statement from RStudio. Are there any options for me or do I need to rethink my process entirely to just use `dbCreateTable()`?

Comment: Can you use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to create the table ?

Comment: If it has to be done in R use the tool that R has for the job

Comment: @Kendle That makes sense. I wanted to check if there was a tool that I didn't know about and couldn't find. But if this is it, this is it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried many options and found the most reliable way to run any SQL code from RStudio Connect and RStudio Server Pro for me was to turn it into a procedure. Then run `DBI::dbSendQuery(con, "SET NOCOUNT ON\nEXEC YourProcedure")`